# Why say "не хуже меня" on one hand, and "не меньше твоего" on the other?

Tags: грамматика

> Ты **не хуже меня** знаешь правила.
>
> [vs]: Я **не меньше твоего** хочу отомстить за нее.

I'm curious to know why you say "не хуже **меня**" instead of  "не хуже **моего**"  on one hand, and "не меньше **твоего**"  instead of "не меньше **тебя**" on the other.

To express the idea of "just as much as I/you do", when do you use the form "не + comparative adverb + **possessive**" instead of the other way round?

Comment: both can be used in both forms, why and when for certain expressions one is preferred over the other is not a simple question to answer, when it's definitely doesn't apply is in sentences referring to 3d person, but it could be because the inflexion of 3d person pronoun is already very similar to the inflexion required by the expression, e.g. **не меньше него** (standard) vs **не меньше его**, but i can imagine its use with adjectivized 3d person pronouns, a feature of dialects, **не меньше ихного/ихнего**, **не меньше евоного**

Comment: Incidentally, when you use the form "не + comparative adverb + someone", the idea of the emphatic "just" is always perceived, right? "**just** as much as I/you do" vs   "as much as I/you do" @БаянКупи-ка

Comment: no, i don't feel it, in English it's indeed quite apt, but not in Russian

Comment: Не хуже меня has literal meaning, not idiomatic. One could just as well say Не лучше меня (opposite sense). Не меньше твоего looks quite idiomatic (with exact sense - no less than you, just as much as you do). The genitive of the pronoun makes it idiomatic (set usage). As alternative cf., Ты не меньше моего изучал эти правила. Note: не меньше моего (твоего) sounds quite colloquial.

Answer (score 3):

> Ты не хуже меня знаешь правила. Ты не хуже моего знаешь правила.(colloquial ).
>
> Я не меньше твоего хочу отомстить за нее.(colloquial ) Я не меньше тебя хочу отомстить.

The constructions are interchangeable.